# Optimize the unique id with in certain period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe called "df" and calculating the sum by unique id called "Id".

Can anyone help me in optimizing the code i have tried.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
df= {'Date':['2019-01-11 10:23:45','2019-01-09 10:23:45', '2019-01-11 10:27:45',
             '2019-01-11 10:25:45', '2019-01-11 10:30:45', '2019-01-11 10:35:45',
             '2019-02-09 10:25:45'],
     'Id':['100','200','300','100','100', '100','200'],
     'Amount':[200,400,330,100,300,200,500],
     }
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `groupby`, after this each adjust within sub-groupby not to the whole df

```
s = {}
for x , y in df.groupby(['Id','NCC']):
    for i in y.index:
        start_date = y['Date'][i] - timedelta(seconds=300)
        end_date = y['Date'][i]

        mask = (y['Date'] >= start_date) & (y['Date'] < end_date)
        count = y.loc[mask]

        count = count.loc[(y['Sys'] == 1)]

        if len(count) == 0:
            s.update({i : 0})
        else:
            s.update({i : count['Amount'].sum()})

df['New']=pd.Series(s)
```

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney that is use the index match at the back end ~ even the length is  diff it will match the index first ~

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to be explicit with something like `idx = count.index.tolist()` and `count = count.loc[(y['Sys'].loc[idx] == 1)]`? I don't know how it affects performance, given the specified size of the real data and the size of the `y`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney you can do that as well ~

Comment: Also, I'm not complaining about your code. It was just an observation from the code in the question and that line of code was bothering me, so I wanted to understand it better. Thanks ;).

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney happy coding

Comment: What if i add (y['Sys'] == 1) directly into mask = (y['Date'] >= start_date) & (y['Date'] < end_date) & y['Sys'] == 1) ? Does it make sense?

Comment: @Maddy6 combine them is making sense ~

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: groupby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort' " error while running your code

Comment: @Maddy6 remove it should be fine

Comment: It Worked :-). Thanks!.... But Can this is efficient in running over 2 million rows? or do we need to change the code for faster processing?

Comment: @Maddy6 with 1.4k rows this code is 3.4x faster than your original code.

Comment: Ok. Can I change dataframe to dictionary with same code? or can you provide alternate code if I have dataframe instead of dictionary... I really thankful if you could help:-)

Answer (score 0):

If the original data frame has 2 million rows, it would probably be faster to convert the 'Date' column to an index and sort it.  Then you can sub select each 5-minute interval:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').sort_index()
df['Sum_Amt'] = 0

for end in df.index:
    start = end - pd.Timedelta('5min')
    current_window = df[start : end]  # data frame with 5-minute look-back
    sum_amt = <calc logic applied to `current_window` goes here>
    df.at[end, 'Sum_Amt'] = sum_amt
    print(current_window)
    print()
```

I'm not following the logic for calculating Sum_Amt, so I left that out.